# How Can I retrieve MP3 metadata by a URL link using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, metadata, mp3

I currently have mp3 files stored on a server, and I have a URL link to fetch them from the server and start playing the audio in a web client (chrome).

My issue is how can I retrieve the mp3 metadata from the URL link (artist, album art, song name)?

Is it even possible to retrieve by a URL link if anyone can point me in the right direct that would be perfect thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript library, which is no longer supported

```
https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader
```

Also you can do it in PHP script on the server side:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php
```